# Undeclared ivars?

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables

I've come across Objective-C code that declares a variable right below the @implementation line in a .m file and not in the @interface block of the .h file.  It then proceeds to use it like a private ivar.  I haven't been able to find documentation about declaring variables this way and would like to know the impact.

Example:

### .h

```
@interface MyClass {
    @private
    int _myPrivInt1;
}
@end
```

### .m

```
@implementation
int _myPrivInt2;
@end
```

### Questions:

What is the technical difference between these two variables?

Is it the same as declaring an ivar in the .h @interface block using the @private modifier or is it more like a C global variable?

Are there any implications when declaring a variable this way?

Should it be avoided?

Is there a term for declaring variables like _myPrivInt2 that would have made my googling a bit more successful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must declare instance variables in interface block.

```
@implementation
int _myPrivInt2;
@end
```

Declaring variable this way you do not actually declare iVar for your class. _myPrivInt2 will be a global variable and can be accessed from any part of your code using extern declaration:

```
// SomeOtherFile.m
extern int _myPrivInt2;
...
_myPrivInt2 = 1000;
```

You can check - your _myPrivInt2 variable will be equal 1000 after code in SomeOtherFile.m executes.

You can also specify static linkage specifier to your _myPrivInt2 so it will be accessible inside current translation unit only

```
@implementation
static int _myPrivInt2; // It cannot be accessed in other files now
@end
```

Comment: I tested your extern idea and it behaved as you described.  This is the reassurance I needed.  What made this ambiguous is that the global variable is declared within the @implementation block which, to me, seems to indicate that it belongs to the class somehow.

Comment: indeed, that is confusing thing. But all variables declared outside the function bodies become global regardless of were they declared inside @implementation block or not

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Do you still need to import your .h file in SomeOtherFile.m to make this work? I'm hoping for a "yes"...

Comment: no, you don't need to import any header - you declare _myPrivInt2 variable in SomeOtherFile.m with external specifier - so linker will look for that instance defined something else